# Executing a function only if a variable is true in python?

Tags: python

for instance say i wanted to print "var is true" only if a variable named myVar = True how would this be possible I've tried a `if myVar = True` and other methods but none of them seem to work

Comment: for comparing the values you should use `==` use `if myVar == True`

Comment: `if myVar == True: print("var is True")`

Comment: It would probably be more pythonic to just say `if myVar:`

Answer (score 2):

one `=` sign is assigning a value, while `==` is for comparison. so: `if myVar == True:` is the right way to check that.

Also, in Python you can simply use `if myVar:` to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something like this:

```
if myVar == True:
    print("var is true")
```

You use `==` to check equality in Python (not to be mistaken with `=`).

You can also ditch the `True` and use:

```
if myVar:
    print("var is true")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can do it in 3 different ways:

```py
if myVar == True:
    # code here

if myVar is True:
    # code here

if myVar:
    # code here
```